# Displaying GeoJSON using Ajax and Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, apache, ajax

I have been trying for days to load a GeoJSON file using Ajax and Leaflet. I can get the map & index.html to load using an Apache server and such but the GeoJSON itself does not show up.

Here is my Head:

```
<!-- ajax plugin -->
<script src="htdocs/webmap101/leaflet.ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<!-- jQuery library -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
  crossorigin=""/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
  crossorigin=""></script>
```

Heres is my Script:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapdiv')
            mymap.setView([19.4,-99.1],11);

          var bl =  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
          mymap.addLayer(bl);

        var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('attractions.geojson', {pointToLayer:
              function(feature, latlng) {
              var str = "<h4>"+feature.properties.name+"</h4><hr>";
              str += "<a href=' " + feature.properties.web+ " ' target = 'blank'";
              str += "<img src='img/"+feature.properties.image+" ' width='200px'";
              str += "</a>";
              return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(str);
            }});
            geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);
```

Chrome developer tools gives me this error:

> GET http://localhost/webmap101/htdocs/webmap101/leaflet.ajax.min.js 404 (Not Found)
>
> index.html:95 Uncaught TypeError: L.GeoJSON.AJAX is not a constructor
>       at index.html:95

Comment: Have you tried `L.geoJSON.ajax(...)` ?

Answer (score 4):

There are several things that have to be corrected.

First thing is wrong path to ajax library `leaflet.ajax.min.js`. Error `404` for file `webmap101/htdocs/webmap101/leaflet.ajax.min.js` tells you that there is no such file on this path on the server. Check it.

Second thing is that statement for including ajax library

```
<script src="htdocs/webmap101/leaflet.ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

has to be placed after statement for including Leaflet library

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
  crossorigin=""></script>
```

Third thing is that even if you correct above errors, there might be problems beacuse geojson layer is added to map before it is actually loaded. Solution for this is adding layer after it has been loaded:

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(
   ...
   ...
}});
geojsonLayer.on('data:loaded', function(){
  geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Ajax call must be **AFTER** leaflet call in the header.

Comment: If you became aware of error in your question after posting it you can edit your question to correct it.